# Umklapp Scattering of electrons by phonons

Tags: solid-state-physics, electrical-resistance, scattering, crystals, phonons

Kittel has a figure in his Solid State text in the free electron chapter depicting the scattering of electrons from phonons.

He explains that, if an electron (with, say, $k=4\pi/5a$) scatters out of the first Brillouin zone of of a phonon (with say, $q=2\pi/5a$) that will result in a large momentum transfer, since we will have:
$$(k=\frac{4\pi}{5a})+(q=\frac{2\pi}{5a}) = (k'=-\frac{4\pi}{5a}) + (G=\frac{2\pi}{a})$$

Due to the introduction of a reciprocal lattice vector, we have changed the sign of the electron's momentum.

I'm having a hard time explaining my complaint here, but I will do my best: Kittel explains this in the free electron chapter, in which case, $k$ and $k'$ are the electron's physical momentum,  *not* their crystal momentum.  In this case, I don't understand why scattering off of this phonon would decrease the electron's physical momentum. **Electrons can and do have momenta greater than $\pi/a$.** Again, I am imagining a free electron picture where the dispersion is a parabola centered about zero and extends out of the FBZ.  Obviously, once we introduce crystal momentum, we are free to fold the dispersion back into the FBZ, but at that point $k$ means something different.  What is happening here?

My only guess is that, in such a collision, physical momentum must be transferred to the lattice. If we considered this collision in physical momentum space, we would define $k$ as I have suggested we are doing for free electrons, allowing values out of the FBZ. Then this collision somehow works out to be the same thing as the electron transferring $8\pi/a$ of its momentum to the lattice.

**Does this make any sense? I am nervous that I am misunderstanding some major concept.**

To be clear, I think I understand the scattering result listed above, if $k$ and $k'$ can be taken to be the electron's crystal momentum. However, this is covered in Kittel before the idea that an electron can have crystal momentum. At that point, $p=\hbar k$, and the scattering result above seems nonsensical to me, since an electron can increase its $k$ out of the FBZ.

Comment: A very important point here is energy conservation.  You can't arbitrarily scatter the electron in any direction from umklapp scattering,  since the process is essentially elastic (the electron energy is constant). What happens instead is that electrons are scattered to other parts of the Fermi surface. I don't fully understand your complaint, but perhaps this helps.

Comment: That does help, actually. I had forgotten that $|k|=|k'|$.  I had been wondering why, in the collision, the electron would not actually simply increase its momentum to something like $k+q$ rather than decrease it to $k+q-G$.  I think the issue is basically that I was thinking of the problem one dimensionally, but in multiple dimensions we can sometimes (even for nonzero $q$) get $|k|=|k+q-G|$.

Comment: The fact that you have a very restricted phase space for where you can scatter in one dimension is related to the fact that Fermi Liquids aren't stable in 1D. Instead you seem to get charge density waves,  and Luttinger Liquids. The latter of which has distinct charge and spin modes while still being "metallic "; all topics that are of interest to modern researchers.